# Variable HTML a JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Tengo un index.html dónde tengo el siguiente código:

```
<script>
    var url = "url"
    s=document.createElement('script');// create script element
    s.src= url;
    document.body.appendChild(s);
    function recuperar(root) {
    var items = root.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];
    var html = [];
    console.log(items);
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        var item     = items[i];
        var title    = item.title;
        console.log(title);
        var pic      = item.galleryURL;
        var viewitem = item.viewItemURL;
}
```

}

Necesito enviar esa variable "item" a mi archivo app.js para trabajar con los datos que están en esa variable. 
PD:Estoy ocupando de servidor express.
Ocupo React y javascript

Comment: ¿a que archivo `app.js` te refieres? (inclúyelo en tu pregunta) ¿ y no te sería mejor mover esa función `recuperar` a tu `app.js`?

Comment: No me funciona si lo pongo en la app.js, solamente me funciona si lo dejo en el index.html, eso es lo que no entiendo, entonces prefiero recuperar los datos del item y mándarlos al app.js, pero no sé si eso se puede hacer

Comment: Tengo la idea de que estás abordando tu problema de una perspectiva incorrecta. En general la manera de trabajar con react no es compatible con algo como un `document.body.appendChild`, lo ideal es que manejes el DOM dentro de tu app react, no se si hayas visto o hecho [algo como esto](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) antes de pensar en tu problema. Te sugiero que expliques bien que es lo que quieres hacer, revisa [ask] y, te insisto, agrega tu `app.js` para que quienes puedan ayudarte tengan más contexto. Saludos